# options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.callback not getting updated dynamically in ember-cli-chart

Tags: ember.js, charts

I have embedded `ember-cli-chart` in my `hbs` file as

```
<div class="chart">
    {{ember-chart type='line' data=data options=options}}
</div>
```

In my component file I have created an **options** property as

```
options: computed('metric', function() {
  let opts = defaultOptions;
  if (this.metric === 'height') {
     opts.scales.yAxes = [{
         ticks: {
             callback: function(value, index, values) {
              // code to return labels
             }
        }
     }]
  } else {
     opts.scales.yAxes = [{
         ticks: {
             callback: function(item, index, items) {
                 // code to return labels
             }
        }
     }]
  }

  return opts;
});
```

I want to display Y-Axis labels based on the current selected metric.
When first time chart loads it renders correct labels on y-Axis and if I change the metric then the same callback is getting used instead of the other one (in else part) and renders same labels but with updated data values.
Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I don't know the addon or `chart.js` for the matter, but when looking at the source code for the [ember-chart](https://github.com/aomran/ember-cli-chart/blob/master/addon/components/ember-chart.js) component, I see

```
didUpdateAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.updateChart();
},

updateChart() {
    let chart   = this.get('chart');
    let data    = this.get('data');
    let options = this.get('options');
    let animate = this.get('animate');

    if (chart) {
        chart.config.data = data;
        chart.config.options = options;
        if (animate) {
            chart.update();
        } else {
            chart.update(0);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in order for `chart.js` to update, you need `didUpdateAttrs` to fire, which means in your case here that `options` itself needs to change. I don't know how you're creating `defaultOptions`, but assuming this reference never changes, there's no reason that `didUpdateAttrs` would fire since you aren't changing the reference to `options` (you're only changing child props of `defaultOptions` in the computed). I would suppose that:

```
import { assign } from '@ember/polyfills';
...
options: computed('metric', function() {
  let opts = assign({}, defaultOptions);
  if (this.metric === 'height') {
     opts.scales.yAxes = [{
         ticks: {
             callback: function(value, index, values) {
              // code to return labels
             }
        }
     }]
  } else {
     opts.scales.yAxes = [{
         ticks: {
             callback: function(item, index, items) {
                 // code to return labels
             }
        }
     }]
  }

  return opts;
})
```

would be enough to trigger the behavior you want since we always return a new object when a recomputation of `options` occurs.

Comment: I tried this solution. Did not work.
I am re-rendering chart within `didUpdateAttrs` method and now it is working.